# Why do we need to group a relation before running Average function in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Please consider this example of pig script ..

I have a small data set as below .. called

### student_details.txt

> 001,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Hyderabad,89
> 002,siddarth,Battacharya,22,9848022338,Kolkata,78
> 003,Rajesh,Khanna,22,9848022339,Delhi,90
> 004,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,Pune,93
> 005,Trupthi,Mohanthy,23,9848022336,Bhuwaneshwar,75
> 006,Archana,Mishra,23,9848022335,Chennai,87
> 007,Komal,Nayak,24,9848022334,trivendram,83
> 008,Bharathi,Nambiayar,24,9848022333,Chennai,72

Idea is to calculate Average of students GPA .

Got the solution by running following commands

> student_details = LOAD '/home/edureka/praveen/files/student_details.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, age:int, phone:chararray, city:chararray, gpa:int);
>
> student_group_all = Group student_details All;
>
> student_gpa_avg = foreach student_group_all  Generate (student_details.firstname, student_details.gpa), AVG(student_details.gpa);

My question is that why do i need to group ALL to find an average .. if there is a simple average function which i could have run directly on student_details. Please help as my common sense goes for a toss .. may be i am using too much of it !!

Comment: Are you wondering why you need to do a `goup by ALL` or why you have to do a `group by`?

Comment: actually my main concern is if there was that we already have a relation which contains all row data .. Average could have been done without grouping ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google **"Aggregate function"** , the following definition comes up -

*In database management an aggregate function is a function where the values of multiple rows are grouped together as input on certain criteria to form a single value of more significant meaning or measurement such as a set, a bag or a list. Common aggregate functions include: Average() (i.e., arithmetic mean) Count().*

Hope this relaxes your common sense a little :)

Comment: I understand but whats the need of an additional aggregation ... We already have a relation which contains student details and average function could have been applied on it ..